# Для пакетов yum install работает некорректно

Tags: centos, rpm, install, yum

При использовании команды `yum -y install` что угодно CentOS выводит ошибки что зеркала не работают

```
http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/fedoraproject.org/epel/7/x86_64/o/openvpn-2.4.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirror.datacenter.by; Unknown error"
```

И так очень много но в конце он скачивает и устанавливает программу.
Я скопировал зеркала. Решил посмотреть может и вправду они не доступны. Но через браузер  если вбить их в адресную строку то они работают.
Что делать?
Да и вчера работала команда `ping google.com` или `ping mail.ru`, а сегодня эти команды выдают ошибку

```
ping: mail.ru: Name or service not known
```

Comment: Похоже на устаревшую версию CentOS. Какая у вас?

Comment: CentOS 7. Нет не устаревшая так как установил примерно 2 недели назад

Comment: Странно. Не знаю тогда. У меня точно такое было на старой пятерке клиента.

Comment: И в самом деле, у вас yum через репо просит пакет для 7 версии, я не заметил. У вас с iptables проблема, похоже.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вчера для настройки OpenVPN поменял настройки iptables. ( Значит из-за этого все

Comment: Верните назад, проверьте. Похоже на то.